# ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el código java me realice la función ascendente?

Tags: java

Hice un código en java y me compila bien, pero no me hace la función ascendente del ordenamiento de los números, lo que pasa es que quiero un programa que haga la función ascendente en java, será que me pueden ayudar a resolverlo por favor. y decirme que es lo que debo agregar o modificar en el código.

```
public class Tarea1 {
    public static void intercambiar(Integer x, Integer y){
        int aux = x;
        x = y;
        y = aux;
    }

    public static void ordIntercambio(int[] a, int n){
        int i;
        int j;
                
        for (i = 0; i < n - 1; i++)
        {
            for (j = i + 1; j < n; j++)
            {
                if (a[i] > a[j])
                {
                    intercambiar(a[i], a[j]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[] a = new int[5];
        a[0] = 3;
        a[1] = 2;
        a[2] = 5;
        a[3] = 7;
        a[4] = 1;
                
        ordIntercambio(a, 5);
                
        for (int x = 0; x < 5; x++){
            System.out.print(a[x]);
            System.out.print("\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
intercambiar(a[i], a[j])

public static void intercambiar(Integer x, Integer y){

   int aux = x;
   x = y;
   y = aux;
}
```

`x` e `y` son dos parámetros, que son **variables locales**, y los valores se pasan como copia. Lo que haces con `intercambiar(a[0], a[1])` es:

- Se obtiene el valor a[0] (3).
- Se obtiene el valor a[1] (2).
- Se invoca `intercambiar(3, 2)`. **Aquí el JVM ya no sabe que estos valores vienen del array**).
- Dentro del método, se hace `x = 3` e `y = 2`.
- Tu método cambia los valores de `x` e `y`, pero no cambia los valores originales.

Lo que tienes que hacer es pasar a intercambio el array (que como es un objeto, no se pasa el array en sí sino una referencia al array, así que modificas el array original) y las posiciones que quieres cambiar, para operar directamente sobre el array.

Aparte de eso, `x` e `y` mejor que sean `int` y no `Integer`, pero eso no te causa el problema.

Tu método `intercambiar` debería tener esta forma:

```
public static void intercambiar(int[], int posicionX, int posicionY) {
   ...
}
```

y cambiar los elementos en las posiciones X e Y.

Comment: Disculpa como seria ya puesto el codigo, fíjese que no entendí muy bien, ya que acabo de empezar el curso de java.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Tarea1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    int [] arr = {1,2,3,4,5};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(invertir(arr)));
}

public static int[] invertir(int [] arr){
    int [] arr2 = new int [arr.length];
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        arr2[i]=arr[(arr.length-1)-i];
    }
    return arr2;
}
}
```

Si entendí bien creo que buscar tener un array de unos valores e invertirlos, este es una solución que hice para hacer eso en la resolución de un ejercicio.

Explicación:

Básicamente a la función le pasas el array que quieres invertir y esta te devuelve un array que estará invertido. Para ello usando un bucle for guardaremos en el nuevo array la ultima posición del array que queremos invertir, para ello usamos la longitud del array restándole 1 para seleccionar el ultimo valor y luego le vamos restando la posición que estamos recorriendo en el bucle.